# How to sub date in datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 datas in datagrid: `2012-03-05 09:00 and 2012-03-05 10:00.`

How to sub one from antoher so value will be 1:00 ? Is it possible?

i was trying this, but without success:

```
MessageBox.Show((dataGridView1[3,0].Value-dataGridView1[5,0].Value))
```

Comment: I think you have to make use of DateTime and TimeSpan objects to do subtraction or other math operation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

Comment: How do you populate the grid ? In general, it's better (and simpler) to adapt the source than trying to retrieve control's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
DateTime dt1;
DateTime dt2;
if(DateTime.TryParse(dataGridView1[3,0].Value,out dt1) 
    && DateTime.TryParse(dataGridView1[5,0].Value,out dt2))
    {
        TimeSpan ts = dt1 - dt2;
        int hours = ts.Hours;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry about that.. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are subtracting `object`s. Try casting to `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
TimeSpan span = dataGridView1[3,0].Value.Subtract ( dataGridView1[5,0].Value );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (seconds): " + span.Seconds );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (minutes): " + span.Minutes );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (hours): " + span.Hours );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (days): " + span.Days );
```